# Rounded dashed lines are plotted in the preview but are not saved - Gnuplot

Tags: linux, plot, scripting, gnuplot

I am trying to plot some data as rounded dashed lines for my paper. When loading my Gnuplot script, the preview shows the rounded dashes. However, after saving the plot as SVG or PDF does not save the round dashed linetype.
I am using Gnuplot 5.4 with terminal wxt round enhanced.
Here is [the image in the preview window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyPAX.png) and
[the saved svg plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtkZC.png)

Thank you. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you save the svg plot by changing the terminal to type "svg" and issuing a `replot` command, or did you use a "save-to-file" widget in the wxt toolbar?   Those are two very different procedures.  Also, both the screen shots you attach are very small.  What is the actual desired size of your final svg or pdf plot?

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Ethan. I am using the "save-to-file" from the widget toolbar. I am not very knowledgeable in the different terminals available in Gnuplot.
As for the small plot, this is just one plot of a 2x4 multiplot hence the small size. I am experimenting with only one plot to see if the changes save or not so I can then add dashed lines to the whole figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for clarifying.  Yes, I can reproduce this problem in the gnuplot 5.4 wxt terminal. The "export to file" widget in the tool bar does not preserve the linecap+linejoin settings from the main window.  In principle you could repair this by editing the output svg file to do a global search and replace changing the text from

```
stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;
```

to

```
stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;
```

A better solution might be to use the `qt` terminal rather than the `wxt` terminal for your initial work. The export-to-file widget attached to the qt plot window does preserve rounded line ends. Note that in the qt terminal the rounded/flat style setting can be toggled in the toolbar widget; this is different from wxt where it can only be changed by a new `set term` command.

Another reasonable work-around is to get your entire script working to your your satisfaction in the wxt terminal itself.  Then run the script again using instead the svg terminal:

```
# Confirm that the script works correctly
set terminal wxt
load 'myfigure.script'
print "If everything looks OK, hit <cr> to write an svg file"
pause -1

# Make sure we are back to a clean starting point     
reset session
set terminal svg standalone size 5in, 3in
set output 'myfigure.svg'
load 'myfigure.script'
unset output
print "All done"
exit gnuplot
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have tried all the suggestions and all of them worked (I did not have the qt terminal so I had to install it). Not only did this solve my problem but I also learned many things about editing svg files and gnuplot terminal. Thanks again.

Comment: By the way, is this a bug in the wxt terminal?

Comment: I guess it depends on whether you consider these settings to be a property of the plot itself or a property of the device you view it on.  I agree it is logical in this case to think that if you set it that way for interactive viewing you would also want it that way when saved for later display on a different device.  But that isn't always true. What if you toggle the background color of an interactive display to "dark mode", but then save the plot as a pdf for printing on paper.  You probably did not intend to introduce a requirement that it be printed on a dark color sheet of paper.